# how to make annotation attribute configuated in application.yml

Tags: spring-boot

I want to configuration internal in the application.yml. but it says atrribute value must be constant. What can I do with this situation?

```
@Value("${robot.internal}")
String internal;


@Scheduled(fixedRate = internal)
public void runAllCheckPoint() {
}
```

Comment: That won't work because by design attributes of an annotation have to be static (as the message tells you to). Use `fixedRateString` and put the placeholder in there. `fixedRateString="${robot.internal}` should do the trick and of course remove the variable as you don't need it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In java `Annotations` can have only constants expression. Because they are processed at compile time. Annotations are metadata (for class, interface, variables, methods or annotations itself), which should not change on run time.

**Valid Usage**

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = "10")
public void runAllCheckPoint() {
}

private static final String FIXED_RATE = "10";

@Scheduled(fixedRate = FIXED_RATE)
public void runAllCheckPoint() {
}
```